# How can I read xml in pig ,where one element - emp_id i having multiple values?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have written pig script org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath(),it it running good when I am having only one 1 emp_id value for the element emp_id but for many it is failing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<returnXml><emp_id>12345,78901,45612,456789,54321</emp_id>
<_Date>12-01-2016</_Date>
</returnXml>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Your example has only one value for emp_id, the string 12345,78901,45612,456789,54321

Comment: HI,no it needed to stored separately,I tried tokenize ,its working thanks for response.